LuaLaTeX, nodes disappear between insert_after and insert_before
I tried to replace " with french quotes and add unbreakable spaces ("mot" to «~mot~»). Unfortunately I do not understand why the nodes between the two spaces disappear with the following code. If I add only one space, everything works perfectly.
Any ideas ?
Thanks
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\luadirect{
local GLYF = node.id("glyph")
local fine = node.new(GLYF)
fine.font=font.current()
fine.char = 160 
function guillemets(head, tail)
  for glyph in node.traverse_glyph(head) do
    texio.write_nl(unicode.utf8.char(glyph.char))
    if glyph.char == 34 then
      if glyph.prev and glyph.prev.id == GLYF
              and not (glyph.prev.char == 40)
      then
        glyph.char = 187
        head,fine = node.insert_before(head,glyph,fine)
      else
        glyph.char = 171
        head,fine = node.insert_after(head,glyph,fine)
      end
    end 
  end
  node.ligaturing(head)
end
}
\luadirect{
  luatexbase.add_to_callback("ligaturing", guillemets, 
  "Guillemets")
}

Voici un "test" !

\luadirect{
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback("ligaturing","Guillemets")
}
\end{document}


Nodes are part of a linked list. Each node has a .next and .prev fields. If you use node.insert_before it updates these fields and the linked list. If you use  node.insert_before twice on the same node, the second time overwrites the first assignment of the fields. For that reason, the function node.copy(<node> n) is provided.

What is expected from the inputs abc"def, abc" def, abc "def, abc("def and abc\kern0pt"def, to mention a few? Or should one just assume that the user is not entering that?

@UdiFogiel Ok thank you. The solution consisting in creating a new fine node as @michal.h21 wrote is one way.

Yes, this way you don't overwrite the original node. But I believe it is slightly less efficient to create nodes than copy them, but I'm not sure

I don't know the exact issue, but I would create a separate glyph each time you insert it to the node list. The following version works:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}


\begin{luacode*}

-- default character numers used if the glyph cannot be find in the curent font
local chars = {
 guillemotleft = 187,
 guillemotright = 171,
 quotedbl = 34,
 parenleft = 40,
}
local penalty_id = node.id "penalty"
local GLYF = node.id("glyph")

local function get_font_char(glyph, font_id)
  -- glyph.char is not directly tied to utf8, in some fonts this can lead to errors
  -- we try to get the character id based on the current font and the glyph name 
  -- fallback is to use the original charcter values defined in the chars table
  if luaotfload then
    local char = luaotfload.aux.slot_of_name(font_id, glyph) 
    return char or chars[glyph]
  end
  return chars[glyph]
end

local function insert_space(head, glyph, fn)
  -- fn should be either node.insert_before or node.insert_after
  -- instead of non-breaking space glyph, use glue and penalties 
  local p1 = node.new("penalty")
  p1.penalty = 10000
  local p2 = node.new("penalty")
  p2.penalty = 10000
  local glue = node.new("glue", 13)
  -- tiny space
  glue.width = tex.sp("0.2em")
  fn(head, glyph, p1)
  fn(head, glyph, glue)
  fn(head, glyph, p2)
end


function guillemets(head, tail)
  for glyph in node.traverse_glyph(head) do
    -- texio.write_nl(unicode.utf8.char(glyph.char))
    if glyph.char == get_font_char("quotedbl",  glyph.font) then
      if glyph.prev and glyph.prev.id == GLYF
              and not (glyph.prev.char == get_font_char("parenleft", glyph.font))
      then
        glyph.char = get_font_char("guillemotright", glyph.font)
        insert_space(head, glyph, node.insert_before)
      else
        glyph.char = get_font_char("guillemotleft", glyph.font)
        insert_space(head, glyph, node.insert_after)
      end
    end 
  end
  node.ligaturing(head)
end
\end{luacode*}
\luadirect{
   luatexbase.add_to_callback("ligaturing", guillemets, "Guillemets")
}


Voici un "test"


\luadirect{
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback("ligaturing","Guillemets")
}
\end{document}



I've changed the code slightly. The values in glyph.char are not Unicode codepoints but glyph positions in the font. They usually correspond to UTF8 values, but not always. Instead of hard-coded character codes, it uses codepoints used by the current font, identified by the glyph name. You can find glyph names here.
The second change is that instead of non-breaking space glyph, we use glue node with penalties which prevents line breaks.
This is the result:


thank you!!! I do not understand why, but that’s fine :).

Can you please explain Why you not testing for "?  Say if I wanted to replace with curly quotes rather than French how can I modify your code?

@yannisl The test if glyph.char == 34 then is checking if the glyph will point to slot 34 of the font, which usually means ". The assignments glyph.char = 187 and glyph.char = 171 are the replacement of " with closing and opening french quotes. If you want to use curly quotes replace the numbers 187, and 171 to the ones you want (font dependent). You might also want to avoid adding the unbreakable space (i.e. avoiding the node.insert_* stuff).

@UdiFogiel  Thanks for the clarification, I mistakenly thought it was pointing to a utf codepoint:) .  It all makes sense now.
